# How to filter on entityBundle using graphql query in drupal

Tags: graphql, drupal-8

I am using the GraphQl api for Drupal 8. Unfortunately I don't know either technology particularly well.

I have the following query

```
query {
  nodeQuery (offset: 0, limit: 23) {
    entities {
      entityLabel
      entityBundle
      entityId
    }
    count
  }
}
```

which returns stuff that looks like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "nodeQuery": {
      "entities": [
        {
          "entityLabel": "Frontpage",
          "entityBundle": "section_page",
          "entityId": "20"
        },
      ....
```

Some of the entities returned are not section_page entities however, so I would like to do a filter that allows me to filter them out.

I have done the following

```
query {
  nodeQuery (offset: 0, limit: 23,filter: {conditions: {field: "entityBundle", value: "section_page", operator: EQUAL}}) {
    entities {
      entityLabel
      entityBundle
      entityId
    }
    count
  }
}
```

which doesn't work and I wouldn't really expect it to that much because obviously entityBundle is not a child of the node, so I should somehow filter on entityBundle inside entities. Haven't figured out how to do it.

The error I get when I run that query is

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Internal server error",
      "category": "internal",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 32,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "nodeQuery",
        "entities"
      ]
    },
    {
      "message": "Internal server error",
      "category": "internal",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 37,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "nodeQuery",
        "count"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "nodeQuery": {
      "entities": null,
      "count": null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out, surprisingly

```
query {
  nodeQuery (offset: 0, limit: 23, filter: {conditions: [
    {operator: EQUAL, field: "type", value: ["section_page"]}]}) {
    entities {
      entityLabel
      entityBundle
      entityId
    }
    count
  }
}
```

since it seems that the type of the field was also the same as the entityBundle value.